# How to filter data and show it in master details view

Tags: sapui5

My Data

link https://api.myjson.com/bins/rwqy

Model

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://api.myjson.com/bins/rwqy");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'data');
```

I want to create a SplitApp(Master-Details page). I have created the Master page as a List of User Name from the User dataset. The list should contain the firstname.

```
var oList = new sap.m.List({
    id:"listId",
    mode: sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelect,
    select: function(){
    oController.itemSelected();
    }
    });
    var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    id: "sList",title:"{data>firstname}"});
    oList.bindAggregation("items","data>/user",oItemTemplate );
    return new sap.m.Page({
        id:"master",
        title: "Claims",
        content: [oList]
    });
```

Now in details page I want to show the expenses made by that user(when i select a specific user from master view) in a table.

Now my question is how to filter data and use it for the Details view. Example:
If I select User "X" from Master view list, I should get id 1 from the "user" and Expenseno 1,4 and 7 (as they are associated with uid 1) from "expense", finally i will show the expenses of uid 1 in the details view.

Code I am trying

```
itemSelected: function(){

var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("appid");//when a item will b selected first we will get instance of our app

var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("listId");//then will get instance of the list

var sitem = list.getSelectedItem();
var spath = sitem.oBindingContexts.data.sPath;

var oitem = sap.ui.getCore().getModel('data').getProperty(spath);
console.log(oitem); //oitem has  Object { id="",  firstname="",  lastname=""} values of the selected user.
//***how to get only the id from "oitem" and filter with expense table***//

//var Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oitem); // will use it for details
//sap.ui.getCore().setModel(Model,'item');//  view(oitem should contain the filtered data)

app.toDetail("detailsid","show");
},
```

Please Help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suppose you reorganize your data source to something like.

```
 [
{
"id": "1",
"firstname": "x",
"lastname": "k",
 "expense": [
{
"expenseno": "1",
            "uid": "1",
            "item": "c",
            "amount": "1500"
        },
        {
            "expenseno": "4",
            "uid": "1",
            "item": "y",
            "amount": "1000"
        },
        {
            "expenseno": "7",
            "uid": "1",
            "item": "q",
            "amount": "900"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "y",
    "lastname": "kalita",
    "expense": [
        {
            "expenseno": "2",
            "uid": "2",
            "item": "t",
            "amount": "1150"
        },
        {
            "expenseno": "5",
            "uid": "2",
            "item": "t",
            "amount": "3500"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "firstname": "z",
    "lastname": "kalita",
    "expense": [
        {
            "expenseno": "6",
            "uid": "3",
            "item": "s",
            "amount": "3500"
        },
        {
            "expenseno": "3",
            "uid": "3",
            "item": "p",
            "amount": "500"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

You can do this from your initial Data set by something like this

```
myData.user.forEach(function(d,i){ 
    var exp = myData.expense.filter(function(d1){

        if(d1.uid === d.id)return true;

        });
    console.log(exp);
    });
```

After this it is just relative binding from parent. /Expense will give all the expenses of parent.
Hope this helps.